# Jenkins not deploying build artifacts over ssh

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am using Jenkins with GitHub to deploy build in the staging server as described in here article- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/continuous-delivery-with-jenkins-and-github-2.html

The build is a success but after build “Execute Shell”  command is not working.

here is error- https://snipboard.io/CZjWsn.jpg

I am using one ubuntu Jenkins server and another deploy server for staging.

```
15:22:27  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/devwork^{commit} # timeout=10
15:22:27  > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/devwork^{commit} # timeout=10
15:22:27 Checking out Revision abde1eeb1e7707173864eccad4fef8e378d9194d (refs/remotes/origin/devwork)
15:22:27  > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
15:22:27  > git checkout -f abde1eeb1e7707173864eccad4fef8e378d9194d
15:22:27 Commit message: "test"
15:22:27  > git rev-list --no-walk abde1eeb1e7707173864eccad4fef8e378d9194d # timeout=10
15:22:27 [test.ojo99] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins384320869397622918.sh
15:22:27 + rm *.gz
15:22:27 rm: cannot remove '*.gz': No such file or directory
15:22:27 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
15:22:27 SSH: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run.
15:22:27 Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your process is trying to remove a file `*.gz` with the `rm` command, try to understand what is this step of the build/copy of you job. Are you removing some file with `rm`? Remove this step and try to build again.

I don't remember any configuration of Jenkins that tries to remove files, but when you copy artifacts, you should put the local path where the file is created and the remote path in the server that is delivering...

Answer (score 0):

You are using rm command which fails because it didn't find any .gz file. you can ignore this error by applying `--force` option

e.g. `rm -f *.gz`